# Android: what is the best way to compress video

Tags: android, video-compression

I know that this question has been asked before, but no one gave a clear answer. Almost Every answer I saw on this topic included the use of what is called `ffmpeg`.

Now I am not an expert in media codec and stuff like that but I understand that `ffmpeg` takes some good time before it compress the video. Not to mention  how complicated the license is for this library.

**My question:**

What is the popular way of doing this, how do we compress a video fast before upload?

I want to give an example of whatsapp, how do they compress the video quickly before upload? Can we do something similar?

**EDIT**

As @CommonsWare suggested yes I mean by compress to reduce the resolution of the video.

Thanks.

Comment: Video files (e.g., MP4) are already compressed. Please explain in detail what you mean by "compress a video". Do you mean "reduce the resolution of the video"? Do you mean "reduce the frame rate of the video"? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes reducing the resoultion.

Comment: @CommonsWare any advice?

Comment: If you are the one recording the video, record it at your desired resolution (within the limits of what that device's camera supports). If you are not recording the video, I am not aware of anything that will change a video's resolution quickly. This is slow on desktop hardware, let alone on mobile devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I am the one recording the video, but my real problem comes when I want to give the media codec the needed width and height, I noticed that all examples on this give 1280 and 720.....If I try to give something lower like 480 by 270 then my output video becomes weirdly cropped eventhough it reduces the size. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to see if the camera supports that resolution, using methods like `hasProfile()` on `CamcorderProfile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible that a device doesn't support a certain resolution for recording?

Comment: Absolutely. *Always* check to see what resolutions the device supports.

Comment: @CommonsWare I will keep that in mind thanks for your help, you are very informative as usual.